# HTML Encode for @Html.TextAreaFor(model =>model.Product.LongDesc ,10,100,null)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have LongDesc field which can have html text and I want to save that in database using model binding. I don't want to skip the xss security part by making ValidateInput to false. Is there any way I can use `@MvcHtmlString.Create` or `@Html.Raw` along with Model binding

Answer (score 1):

You could set [AllowHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx) attribute on `LongDesc` field and use [AntiXSS](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/AntiXSS) library to check input value.

Comment: My problem is LongDesc is the part of product entity which is entity framework. Can I use ValidateInput(false) at Controller & use AntiXSS at controller to verify the content?

Comment: If it's a class generated by EF you can use buddy class and set AllowHtml on it's LongDesc property.

Comment: Thanks frennky. I created a buddy class as below      [Bind()]
    public class ProductAnnotations
    {
        [AllowHtml]
        public string LongDesc { get; set; }
    } http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx